# How do I spread a formula through a column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has a column for the date that a document was requested. I want to have a column that calculates how many days that request is pending and if its over 30 days highlight it. I understand the conditional formatting part. Is there an easy way to put the =TODAY()-A2 down the whole column without having to type each one separately?

Thank you.

Comment: See [How to fill a formula down in adjacent cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6)

Comment: When working with Today which is volatile it would make things quicker if you put `=TODAY()` in a cell like Z1 then reference that cell absolutely: `=$Z$1-A1` then fill down.  TODAY is volatile and recalcs every time Excel recalcs.  so limiting the number of formulas with it will speed things up.

Comment: @ScottCraner, every dependent formula will also recalculate; e,g, the ones that reference the cell containing the volatile function like `=$Z$1-A1`

Comment: @Jeeped even if the data does not change?  I thought only if the value changed and since TODAY() only changes once a day that would be the only time the others calculated, but hey, I am probably wrong, would not be the first nor the last.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I might test this but I believe if a function returns 1 and it recalculates and is still 1 then the calculation makes it 'dirty' and forces recalc down the line.

Comment: @ScottCraner, looks like the situation follows my synopsis unfortunately. Debug.print Timer reports the same interval in Worksheet_Calculate no matter whether I change a value on another worksheet or clear/rewrite Z1 with today() so a complete recalc is performed in either event.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would want to replicate your formula in column C starting at row 2, then you can replicate this instantly by selecting cell C2 (the cell containing your first formula), and then double-clicking on the tiny box on the bottom right of your selection. This instantly fills in column C with your formula adjusted per row until the last row of your data.

Comment: pretty picture at https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8faE.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQTF6.png